# ReflectedSchemas folder in the user's AppData folder (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, temporary-files

Today I ran [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to check what is filling up my harddisk. I was surprised to see that this folder contains 4.6 GB (!):

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas
```

What is the purpose of this folder and the files it contains? Is there a way to get rid of these files in a safe way?

*Thanks!*

Comment: This question is useful for people receiving the following errors:

  Validation (): Element .. is not supported.
  'asp' is an unrecognized tag prefix or device filter

Remove the contents of your ReflectedSchemas folder. These XSD schemas are generated on demand when you compile a web controls. Just remove the and Visual Studio will regenerate the schemas when needed.

https://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2004/05/14/131949.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've tried to empty the folder completely, and have no problems found since i've done.  When launching a project in VS, a new schema was created.

Edit: you can also move the folder and put it back when you believe you screwed things up...

Comment: When I emptied the folder I found I'd lost all intellisense when working with ascx files. Completely deleting the ReflectedSchemas folder and restarting Visual Studio seemed to correctly regenerate the required xsd.

Answer (score 3):

This drives me crazy and hopefully it will be fixed in VS 2010; however, I found another solution to this problem.

My "fix" is to use the "Junction" tool to map the folder to another drive.  If you're like me and have a second drive, then you can use window's Junction tool to create something like a symbolic link to map the folder to another drive.

Best of all, you no longer need to use the command line.  This freeware tool works great: [Junction Link Magic](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm).

Comment: Hermann Schinagl also has a free program Hard Link Shell Extension which I have used with some success in the past. Available at: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html This program is useful if if you just want to link a file instead of a folder (a hard link)

Answer (score 2):

These files caused problems for me because I was using Windows' Roaming Profiles feature, so I symlinked (created symbolic links for) them to the Local AppData folder:

```
cd %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0
mklink /D ReflectedSchemas ..\..\..\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas
mklink /D ReflectedTypeLibs ..\..\..\..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedTypeLibs
```

If your needs/problems regarding these files differ from mine, you can link them to a different folder, even on a different partition. (You can use the `/J` switch instead of `/D`, and in this case, it probably won't matter, but it does help to know [the differences between the different types](https://superuser.com/q/67870/45163) of links.)