# Can the contents of C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas be deleted safely?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I need to reclaim drive space and noted that I have close to 2 GB in C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ReflectedSchemas.  What is the purpose of the this share and can I purge these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:
[ReflectedSchemas folder in the user's AppData folder (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878345/reflectedschemas-folder-in-the-users-appdata-folder-visual-studio)

Doesn't really answer the question, but it seems safe to delete it.