# No more Intellisense for ASP tags visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm not getting intellisense for asp tags anymore in websites or web applications.
There is a check mark for the following:

- Tools->Options->Text
  Editor->C#->General->Auto list
  members

  Tools->Options->Text
  Editor->C#->General->Parameter
  information

  Tools->Options->Text
  Editor->C#->Intellisense->Show
  completion list after a character is
  typed

My dev environment is server 2008 R2 64 bit, VS 2010 Ultimate (ver 10.1.30319.1 RTMRel), I don't have resharper installed, but I do have AnkhSVN installed.

How do I get intellisense back?

UPDATE: Here is my webconfig:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MerchandiseEntitiesContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Merchandise.Entities.csdl|res://*/Merchandise.Entities.ssdl|res://*/Merchandise.Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=OldOslernet;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800"
              maxRequestLength="1048576"
              useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" />
    </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="upLoadPath" value="images/products/"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Also, here is a pic of the editor:
http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/958/extension.png

Comment: I've moved the project into subversion and downloaded the project to another machine and the intellisense works fine.  So it's not a project/solution issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Delete Schema Files**

Delete all files in the following folder: C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas.  It is [safe to delete anything in this folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878345/reflectedschemas-folder-in-the-users-appdata-folder-visual-studio) as Visual Studio will regenerate them as needed.

**Unblock Referenced Assemblies**

There could be a problem with one of the referenced assemblies in your project being blocked on your machine.  Right-click on each DLL in Windows Explorer, select Properties, and click the "Unblock" button (if the DLL is being blocked.)

**Reset Visual Studio Settings**

If all else fails, you can try to reset your settings in Visual Studio 2010 ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=VS.100).aspx).)  You'll have to tweak your settings all over again but it is worth trying.

Comment: Blocked dll was it.  You, sir, rock.  Fiercely!

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from blowing away a dev environment.
Worth every point.  Cheers!

Comment: I'm trying to award the bounty, but after I click it, it says that I have 12 hours to award the bounty and the button doesn't change.
Please let me know if you have not received the bounty.
Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.  It's a good general trick to remember if you run into similar issues with other files.  Copying files from machine to machine may result in files being blocked by Windows.

Comment: It should be possible to award the bounty now.  There is a 24 delay after a bounty is created that prevents awarding.

Comment: I clicked it again and it's same deal.

Comment: Good news is that it will award it to you automatically in less than 24 hours.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Deleting the schema files worked instantly for me in VS 2017! Just had to close and reopen the file, and saw the schemas being regenerated and got intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me for aspx/ascx files:

Right click on the file in Solution Explorer
Select Open With
Select Web Form Editor (Default)
Click Set as Default

Comment: This simple fix worked for me in VS2017.  I closed the problem file and then right click Open with >> Web Forms Editor.

Answer (score 0):

- Check *file extension - editor* bindings in preferences.
- Check the **system.web\pages\controls** config section in your web configuration file.
- Check the **system.web\compilation\assemblies** section too.

Comment: There is nothing listed under Microsoft C# in the extension editor

Comment: The project is a .net 4.0 project, so there isn't anything under those sections by default.  Should there be?

Comment: If your project is built with .NET 4, no. But give it a try to add those lines to your config file from a .NET 2/3 project.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  No go on that one