# No Intellisense for Angular/Bootstrap in ASPX files on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

I do get Intellisense with editing plain HTML (*.html) files in Visual Studio 2015. I mean that I get proper autocomplete when I type in a ng-* attribute or a Bootstrap style.

But there's no way to get that when I edit a Masterpage or a regular ASPX page. No autocomplete and the tags gets underlined (not recognized).

What am I missing to get it working ?

Thanks for your kind help.

Popal

Comment: Add a sample code

Comment: Check these option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684870/no-more-intellisense-for-asp-tags-visual-studio-2010