# VisualStudio.bak inside Roaming folder is extremely large. Can I delete it?

Tags: visual-studio

When I look at the following folders, they are exteremely large.

C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio (12GB)
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio.bak (36GB)

What is VisualStudio.bak folder for? Can I delete VisualStudio.bak folder (since it has bak extension)?

Thanks in advance!

**Answer:** I found similar post here.

[ReflectedSchemas folder in the user's AppData folder (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878345/reflectedschemas-folder-in-the-users-appdata-folder-visual-studio)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2004/05/14/131949.aspx

Comment: As far as i remember bak files where some backup data. What you can do is move them to a temporarty folder for a few days and use your VS as normal.. if it breaks you know why. I doubt it will though.. but 36GB? wierd..

Comment: Hmm, I have AutoRecover enabled and those directories are under 10 MB on my machine. I use Visual Studio pretty extensively, but it is not open at the moment. Don't delete the files while it's open!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes, they are backup files created by Visual Studio for Auto Recovery.

Long Answer:

Let me explain, this is a visual studio feature to recover your solution files wherever something bad happens, and really you should keep this in mind. That auto recover can save you a lot of time when something on your system goes wrong, for example, if you laptop battery suddenly dies on you ‘seen that, done that…’

Visual studio simply creates an backup of your files with the extension .bak, you can try opening the files and see that it’s just a backup of an solution file.

But, if you keep your solution on source control you can save some time by disabling this feature, here’s how.

You need to deselect the AutoRecover setting to stop backup files if from being created:

Go to Tools->Options->Environment->AutoRecover (check that the “Show All Settings” is enabled) and just uncheck the AutoRecover option.

Tools -> Option

At this point you can clean the solution, just make a search in solution directory on your disk and delete every .bak file. 
And that’s it, from now visual studio will stop creating that pesky files on your solution, but keep in mind that this is a feature to help you in case something wrong happens, but if you are connected to a source control it can save you some time and spare working in you solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are those *.xsd files recovery files inside C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio.bak\9.0.bak\ReflectedSchemas? If so, they are no longer needed once VS is closed properly?

Comment: If I am not wrong, from what I can remember, they are caching information for intellisense. I think they would be created as we explore different sections of code in the solution.

Comment: @winmyan, could you please mark this as answered, (ofcourse if your happy with it) so that others in the community can focus on answering other questions and help me earn some reputation points ;) Thanks -Ram

Comment: You rock. I also added similar post so that it'll be useful for the community. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878345/reflectedschemas-folder-in-the-users-appdata-folder-visual-studio