# Can't reference controls in code behind. Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

There are quite a few questions out there regarding this (for me, recurring) issue, but none of them have solved my problem.

*Problem:*

Whatever control I add in my aspx page, it is not recognised in the codebehind. Compiling doesn't work, because the ID is not recognised.

*None of the following worked:*

- Clean and rebuild solution.
- Close and open VS
- Delete asp.net temp files
- Check project's target framework.
- Check assemblies are all there.
- Check designer viewn to see if the control is actually there (it is)
- Get control's ID with JS function to check it is the intended one (it is)

The problem has started only recently. In fact, I can reference the older controls fine.
The problem is observed both with standard ASP controls and Telerik ones.

Does anyone know of something else I should try? Please help me, I'm in the middle of a project and this is causing unnecessary delays, ta.

Comment: are you refrencing your controls right in your asp page? do you give the controls valid IDs. are you applying a code behind sytax that your page can refrence to?

Comment: I get this regularly but in VS2010. The only way I've been able to solve this is to regularly clear the ReflectedSchemas directory. I have  a bat file that does this and then opens VS. For my vesrion of VS2010 the directory location is C:\Users\USER\AppData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas I think that VS2012 is version 11.0

Comment: If you are using TFS as source control, try removing the "get all when solution is opened" checkbox. It causes VS to sometimes fail to update the designer file of the page and this breaks control references.
Also, you can try using a website type of solution to avoid having designer files at all.

Comment: @Johnny i don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Mych I can't find that folder. Could you point me to the resource you've found about this please? thanks

Comment: Dura, Just do a search for a directory called ReflectedSchemas and delete all the files within it. I can't remember where I got this information from and its not an elegant solution but it has helped me.

Comment: Mych I've found the folder and deleted its content, but still no joy. the weird thing is that the problem arises only on one particular page in my application. Any further ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no.... although I did find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878345/reflectedschemas-folder-in-the-users-appdata-folder-visual-studio which had a better explanation of the files in this directory. Always delete the file with VS closed or at the very least with no project open. Interestingly both my mac-mini and my work pc run win7 and VS2010. The mac-mini i7 16g ram running a 4g windows virtual in Parallels 9 has never had this issue.

Comment: thanks Mych, I've solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my issue. For a full account of it, please refer to the comments above.

1. I've noticed that although my project was already of web application type, designer files weren't showing.
2. I've forced the designer files to be recompiled by clicking on the ''convert to web application' option

I was then able to reference the control ID.

Thanks to the commentators anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of your asp.net controls (in the .aspx file) have the:

```
runat='server'
```

tag... Without this, you will not be able to reference the controls.

e.g.

```
<asp:Label runat='server' Text='Test Label' ID='TestLabel' />
```

Hope this helped...

Rodit

Comment: thanks but I've done that. I forgot to include it in my list of things I had tried.

Comment: If that is so, the only thing I would suggest is trying to run your asp page with IIS EXPRESS GUI which is open source and free (just google it). If that does not work either, I would recommend you restart the project...

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, due to the fact that I was using the pre-generated Login page. My solution was to change this section from this:

```
<asp:Login runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled"   RenderOuterTable="false">
<LayoutTemplate>
```

To this:

```
<asp:Login ID="asplogin" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
<LayoutTemplate>
```

basically, I just added an ID to the asp:Login which allowed me to access the objects in the code from behind by prefixing the control name with asplogin

asplogin.youControlNameHere